# Change Duration from (Years and Month) to (Month) in R

Tags: r

I have some data frame like below. I need to add a "Duration" column beside the "Years and Month" column and convert the "Years and Month" to Month as duration.

For instance, I need to change the 2Y3M to 27M.

I have searched for it and didn't succeed. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

| Years and Month | Percentage Change |
| --- | --- |
| 2Y3M | 13% |
| 3Y4M | 23% |

Comment: Is that 'Years and Month' column just text strings, or an actual duration object created by some package?

Comment: @thelatemail Just text strings. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: `2Y3M` should be 27 months right?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, should be 27 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` and column as `ym` you can use `strcapture` to extract year and month value.

```
result <- transform(strcapture('(\\d+)Y(\\d+)M', df$ym, 
                    proto = list(year = integer(), month = integer())), 
                    yearmonth = (year * 12) + month)
result

#  year month yearmonth
#1    2     3        27
#2    3     4        40
```

---

To assign the value to same column.

```
df$ym <- transform(strcapture('(\\d+)Y(\\d+)M', df$ym, 
           proto = list(year = integer(), month = integer())), 
          yearmonth = (year * 12) + month)$yearmonth
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I need to select the yearmonth column of result dataframe and add it to original dataframe?

Comment: You replace `df` with your dataframe name and `ym` with the name of the column that you have.

Comment: There are so many good answers here... I will think carefully to pick only one.

Comment: How do I replace the "Years and Month" column data with the calculated data?

Comment: See updated answer. You can extract the value and assign it to the same column. Replace `df$ym` with your dataframe and column name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why add $yearmonth to the last line?

Comment: `transform` returns a dataframe with additional columns we don't need them.  As we are interested only in `yearmonth` column we extract it using `$yearmonth`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few approaches.  See Note at the end for the input `x`.

**1)** Convert to `yearmon` class which stores its input internally as year+(month-1)/12.  We can get the internal number by converting it to numeric, then multiply by 12 and add back the 1.

```
library(zoo)

ym <- as.yearmon(x, "%YY%mM")
12 * as.numeric(ym) + 1
## [1] 27 40
```

This could be written as a one-liner like this:

```
12 * as.numeric(as.yearmon(x, "%YY%mM")) + 1
```

**1a)** Using `ym` from above this would also work where `as.integer` extracts the year and `cycle` gets the month:

```
12 * as.integer(ym) + cycle(ym)
## [1] 27 40
```

**2)** A base solution would be to read in `x` splitting it into a 2 column data frame which is converted to a matrix. matrix multiply that by `c(12, 1)` to get the result.

```
d <- read.table(text = x, sep = "Y", comment.char = "M")
c(as.matrix(d) %*% c(12, 1))
## [1] 27 40
```

This could also be written as a one-liner:

```
c(as.matrix(read.table(text = x, sep = "Y", comment.char = "M")) %*% c(12, 1))
```

### Note

The input `x` in reproducible form is

```
x <- c("2Y3M", "3Y4M")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "Years and Month" column is a character type, I would extract the years and months separately, then figure out how many months it is.

```
library(tidyverse)

your_df <- tibble(`Years and Month` = c("2Y3M", "3Y4M"))

your_df %>%
   mutate(years = str_extract(`Years and Month`, "^\\d+(?=Y)"),
           months  = str_extract(`Years and Months`, "(?<=Y)\\d+")) %>%
   mutate(total_months = as.numeric(years)*12 + as.numeric(months))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!